# Htaccess Rewrites with FastCGI

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, fastcgi

I am currently in the process of transferring to Fast CGI from the apache module. However, one thing that has struck me is that I have configured a lot of settings and rewrites in my htaccess file for apache.

Can I achieve the same things in FastCGI that I have done in my htaccess file?

These things include:

Rewrite conditions for redirecting ***example.com*** to ***www.example.com***

Rewrite rules for converting ***example.com/test*** to ***example.com/test.php***

And more complex... ***example.com/test/archive/1*** to ***example.com/test.php?archive=true&id=1***

Applying custom error documents like this ***ErrorDocument 400 /errors/error.php?code=400***

Is there a website that shows the equivalent of htaccess rules and FastCGI rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these things have nothing to do with FastCGI or the Apache module for PHP.  They'll work just fine.

Apache is still doing the rewrite work, and that is what your `.htaccess` directives are for, in this case.  Instead of calling it's module to handle PHP, it just executes PHP via FastCGI.  That's all.

Comment: That is embarrassing. Wasn't thinking correctly as I actually knew that!! The only thing I cannot do is define php directives in my htaccess! I think.

Comment: thanks for this! early morning, no coffee... Google to the rescue! by increasing my intelligence level, with Q/A posts on StackOverFlow :P